# Python Selenium Soloution

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

I Want A Soloution With Python Selenium Web Driver Please !!

I am trying to refresh page untill dates is available in calendar
I Want To stop refresh when the dates is available 
And I Want To Choose Any Date Automaticly

Comment: The question  needs to be more specific in order for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check if an element exists is to simply call `find_element` inside a `try/catch`. For example :

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id("<the id>")
        break
    except:
        driver.refresh()
```